# moment.js format current datetime in multiple timezones

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I need Pacific time US & Canada in my javascript code. I am using below line of code for that

```
moment(new Date()).zone("-07:00").format('hh:mm A')
```

but if daylight is on then static -07:00 will give incorrect output

How to get current server time in JavaScript using moment.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont state what canadian time zone you want, but moment.js's [`timezone` add on](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) is likely what you need. With that you can do something like the below which has internal support for DST and not DST:

```js
var pacific    = moment.tz("US/Pacific");
var canada = pacific.clone().tz("Canada/Eastern"); 

console.log(pacific.format('hh:mm A'));
console.log(canada.format('hh:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.1/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DelightedD0D appreciated.